# Ping Test Batch File to Text Output of Results

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, ping

I wrote a very simple .bat file that pings 6 IP Addresses on start up and then pauses the window so I can go through and make sure each is responding.

I was wondering if it would be possible to create an output .txt file that simplifies the results. Instead of an output of something like:

```
Pinging www.google.com [74.125.226.17] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.226.17: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=51
Reply from 74.125.226.17: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=51
Reply from 74.125.226.17: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=51
Reply from 74.125.226.17: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 74.125.226.17:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 9ms, Average = 9ms
```

in a .txt file it would only read something like "%servername% is online and responsive" or "%servername% is NOT responsive," when reporting packet loss.

I'm not sure if this would be possible with a simple batch file but if not, can anyone point me in the right direction of another language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "servername=www.google.com"
ping %servername% |find "TTL" >nul && echo %servername% is online || echo %servername% is offline
```

you may want to play with `ping`s Parameters `/n` and `/w`